# How to recursively convert all the arrays in a JSON string to a dataset in Delphi?

Tags: json, delphi

I have a JSON string that I want to convert into datasets, each JSONarray will be another dataset. So far I was able to isolate the arrays on the string and adding them into a table, showing the values in a grid. But on second iteration, the array loses the outer brackets due to how the JSON was made. For security reasons I cannot post here the complete JSON object, I'll post a similar one

```json
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "field1": "text",
        "field2": [
            {
                "fieldx": "value"
            }
        ],
        "field3": [
            {
                "field1": "value",
                "field2": "value",
                "field3": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the code I produced so far, but when it reaches field3 it throws a parse error when I try to convert the string `"field3":[{"field1":"value", "field2":"value", "field3":0}]`:

```delphi
procedure TForm2.VerificaTabela(aJSON: string);
var
  JSONArr: TJSONArray;
  JSONVal, JSONVal2, JSONTxt: TJSONValue;
  JSONObj: TJSONObject;
  i: integer;
  dummymemtable: TFDMemtable;
  dummyds: TDataSource;
  dummygrid: TDBGrid;
begin
  if aJSON <> EmptyStr then
  begin
    // =================================
    dummygrid := TDBGrid.Create(Form2);
    dummyds := TDataSource.Create(Form2);
    dummymemtable := TFDMemtable.Create(Form2);
    dummyds.DataSet := dummymemtable;
    dummygrid.DataSource := dummyds;
    dummygrid.Align := TAlign.alTop;
    dummygrid.Parent := ScrollBox1;
    dummygrid.Name := '';
    // =================================

    JSONVal := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(aJSON);

    if JSONVal <> nil then
      JsonToDataset(dummymemtable, JSONVal);

    JSONTxt := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(aJSON);
    if JSONTxt <> nil then
      for JSONVal in JSONTxt as TJSONArray do
      begin
        JSONObj := JSONVal as TJSONObject;
        for i := 0 to JSONObj.Count - 1 do
          if JSONObj.Pairs[i].JsonValue is TJSONArray then
          begin
            VerificaTabela(JSONObj.Pairs[i].ToJSON);
          end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Any Ideas on how I could make this code work? The code is based on the premise that I don't know the lenght of the JSON nor its contents, so it has to work for every case.

Comment: I can help you turning JSON into Data Objects. I've written at tool doing that. I yes it support arrays, and I can easily parse the json given here

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataSet-Serialize:
https://github.com/viniciussanchez/dataset-serialize

Comment: Thanks for sharing your work but I am looking for a native IDE way of doing it.